# “Sans quoi” peut-il être suivi par la phrase au présent ?

Tags: grammaire, usage, temps-grammatical, mode-grammatical

> Range ta chambre, sans quoi tu ne pourras recevoir tes amis.

> Le reportage  montre l’urgence de certaines mesures à prendre, sans quoi la situation empirait de façon irréversible.

Dans les cas d’exemplaires,  je ne vois que des phrases se suivent par un futur simple ou conditionnel présent.

Donc, est-il possible de construire la phrase « passé composé + sans quoi + présent »?

> Il n’a pas cessé de trouver son travail sans quoi il ne gagne pas sa croûte.

Comment: chercher du travail, plutôt.

Comment: @Lambie J'en doute. On ne gagne pas sa vie en cherchant du travail.

Comment: **Il n’a pas cessé de chercher du travail sans quoi il ne gagne[rait] pas sa croûte**. Mal dit mais au moins l'idée y est.

Comment: @Lambie Pas mieux.

Comment: @jlliagre You rewrite it then: Il n’a pas cessé de trouver son travail sans quoi il ne gagne pas sa croûte.

Comment: _Il n'a pas cessé de chercher du travail sans quoi il ne pourra pas gagner sa croûte (éventuellement)_ C'est bizarre. Plutôt: _il ne cesse de chercher du travail, dans l'espoir de pouvoir gagner sa croûte (sous-entendu: un jour, quand il aura trouvé du travail)_?

Answer (score 2):

J'ai dû lire ta phrase plusieurs fois avant d'avoir une idée de ce que tu cherchais à dire, donc je ne la recommanderais pas.

- *Ne pas cesser de trouver son travail* n'est pas idiomatique.
- Le présent de la subordonnée ne concorde pas avec le passé composé de la principale.

Pour avoir une phrase idiomatique, tu aurais pu écrire :

> Il n'a pas cessé de trouver des petits boulots, sans quoi, il n'aurait pas pu gagner sa croûte.

Il subsiste néanmoins un problème car la phrase reste une tautologie. Gagner sa croute, c'est travailler. Le sens est donc : *Il n'a pas cessé de travailler sans quoi, il n'aurait pas pu travailler*...

Voici quelque chose de plus idiomatique (merci @XouDo pour *enchaîner les petits boulots*):

> Il a enchaîné petit boulot sur petit boulot, sans quoi il ne s'en serait pas sorti financièrement.

Comment: par contre, **ne pas cesser de chercher du travail** est idiomatique.

Comment: @Lambie Oui mais la phrase complète n'a alors plus de sens. Ce n'est pas ce que l'OP souhaitait exprimer.

Comment: Comment sais-tu ce qu'il veut dire?? Il n’a pas cessé de chercher du travail,  Il a besoin d'un travail sans quoi il ne gagne[rait] pas sa croûte.

Comment: @Lambie Je n'ai pas de doute sur ce qu'il veut dire car j'ai compris sa phrase. Il ne parle pas de chercher du travail mais d'en trouver, ce qui est quand même très différent. Chercher du travail, c'est être au chômage, donc être peu ou pas indemnisé, suivant le contexte, trouver un travail, c'est être rémunéré.

Comment: Peut-être encore plus idiomatique : *enchaîner les petits boulots/les contrats précaires.*

Answer (score 2):

C'est assez rare, mais je ne vois pas d'objection à utiliser le présent après *sans quoi*.

Sur [cette page](https://www.cairn.info/revue-travaux-de-linguistique-2004-2-page-81.htm#s2n3), il est expliqué que *sans quoi* peut être utilisé *"dans un registre peu soutenu, indépendamment de toute structure hypothétique"* (la structure hypothétique est la raison pour laquelle on trouve du conditionnel ou du futur).

On y trouve les exemples suivants :

> Un contrat implique le libre accord des partenaires, sans quoi ce n’est plus un contrat.

> Il vaut mieux ne pas parler japonais dans les relations de travail. Sans quoi on devient soi-même un peu japonais.

Ce n'est probablement pas le meilleur choix en terme de construction de phrase, mais rien ne l'interdit à proprement parler.

Comment: Mais dans ces examples, c'est le présent qui est suivi par le présent, pas le passé composé. Une bonne trouvaille, quand même.

Answer (score 1):

Je me penche sur la qustion depuis plusieurs jours déjà, et je ne trouve qu'une formulation alliant **présent de l'indicatif** à **présent de l'indicatif** :

- "*Il ne doit* pas cesser de chercher du travail, sans quoi *il ne peut* pas gagner sa croûte."

La seule construction qui me vient avec **passé composé de l'indicatif** et **présent de l'indicatif** est du genre :

- "*Il n'a pas cessé* de chercher du travail, sans quoi *il ne peut* pas gagner sa croûte, afin de nourrir sa famille."

Cependant, la particule du *"sans que" + sujet + verbe + complément* est ici facultative et agit comme une précision concernant l'action de chercher du travail, et peut totalement être mise entre paranthèses, voire retirée de la phrase.